# How to add legend based on color in scatterplot [matplotlib]

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to add legend based on the color in a scatter plot in matplotlib. I have seen several example but they assume that each plot will have a label associated to it, and I haven't figure out how to do it without the "label" property and only base it on color. Currently I have the following code

```
plt.subplot(121)
plt.gca().set_title('Female')
survived = female_data[:,1]
pclass = female_data[:,2]
age = female_data[:,5]
label_color = ['r' if i==0 else 'b' for i in survived]
axes = plt.gca()
axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.scatter(age, pclass, color=label_color)
```

Which render something like this, I want red and blue to have a single label in the plot. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: I think you could do this with `plt.plot(age[np.argwhere(survived)], age[np.argwhere(survived)], 'bo', age[np.argwhere(~survived)], age[np.argwhere(~survived)], 'ro')` or something similar. If you use just markers and no lines. See https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: plot with legend]

https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=1RtdwW8ztZbBUpd67RWffKRVt0ae0dNkr

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ages = np.array([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2])
pclass = np.arange(10)
survived = np.array([
    True, True, True, False, False,
    False, True, False, True, False
])
plt.plot(
    pclass[survived], ages[survived], 'bo',
    pclass[~survived], ages[~survived], 'ro'
)
plt.legend(['survived', 'died'])
```

Hopefully you can see my colab notebook or the image. Is this what you wanted? I don't think you want `scatter`.

Comment: it seems that this is the only solution, even if can do it with scatter, I could take this strategy and use labels, It would be nice if there could be an option to do it directly with the scatter plot and the colors already defined, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an array of values to legend in the same order you define color in scatter it should work.

label = ['0', 'else']
plt.legend(labels)

Comment: I've just made the [`StackOverflow.ipynb` colaboratory notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RtdwW8ztZbBUpd67RWffKRVt0ae0dNkr) public, sorry for any inconvenience: